# Postgres Data Directory disk space suddenly spike and fall

Tags: postgresql

my postgres data directory suddenly rise from 70% to 98% for about 5 to 10 mins and then fall back to 70%.my backups, archive and wals are on different mount points separate from the data mount point. I check the insert, update and delete metric from datadog during that time but did not see any significant spike. I am trying to figure out what could have cause the data disk to spike

Comment: Could you look for a `SELECT` query that (maybe accidentally) requested an immense quantity of data? In that case the dbserver may have stored the result it was building in temporary files - if they reside on the same disk as the db of course.

Comment: Ttemporary files for on-disk sorting could be involved too. Probably impossible to tell exactly what unless you were logging this sort of thing beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Some of your queries sort a lot of rows or perform similar memory-intense operations. If `work_mem` is exceeded, PostgreSQL writes temporary files that only live for the duration of a single statement.

Set `temp_file_limit` to keep rogue SQL statements from filling your data disk with temporary files.